# How to split a dataframe using pandas?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split

I have following dataframe to process,
DF

```
Name                City
Hat, Richards       Paris
Adams               New york
Tim, Mathews        Sanfrancisco
chris, Moya De      Las Vegas
kate, Moris         Atlanta
Grisham HA          Middleton
James, Tom, greval  Rome
```

And my expected dataframe should be as following, DF

```
Name         Last_name           City
Hat          Richards            Paris
             Adams               New york
Tim          Mathews             Sanfrancisco
chris        Moya De             Las Vegas
kate         Moris               Atlanta
             Grisham HA          Middleton
James, Tom   greval              Rome
```

Splitting should be done on last ',' and if there is no ',' then entire other words or phrase should fall in column 'Last_name' and 'Name' column should remain vacant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`radd`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.radd.html) for add `,`, last [`str.lstrip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.lstrip.html):

```
df[['first','last']] = df['Name'].radd(', ').str.rsplit(', ', n=1, expand=True)
df['first'] = df['first'].str.lstrip(', ')
print (df)
                 Name          City       first        last
0       Hat, Richards         Paris         Hat    Richards
1               Adams      New york                   Adams
2        Tim, Mathews  Sanfrancisco         Tim     Mathews
3      chris, Moya De     Las Vegas       chris     Moya De
4         kate, Moris       Atlanta        kate       Moris
5          Grisham HA     Middleton              Grisham HA
6  James, Tom, greval          Rome  James, Tom      greval
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `str.split` with `n=-1`(This is default you can change what you need)

```
newdf=df.Name.str.split(', ',expand=True,n=1).ffill(1)
newdf.loc[newdf[0]==newdf[1],0]=''
newdf
Out[923]: 
       0          1
0    Hat   Richards
1             Adams
2    Tim    Mathews
3  chris     MoyaDe
4   kate      Moris
5         GrishamHA
df[['Name','LastName']]=newdf
df
Out[925]: 
    Name          City   LastName
0    Hat         Paris   Richards
1              Newyork      Adams
2    Tim  Sanfrancisco    Mathews
3  chris      LasVegas     MoyaDe
4   kate       Atlanta      Moris
5            Middleton  GrishamHA
```

Answer (score 4):

### Quick and Dirty

Use `pandas.str.split` with `str[::-1]` to reverse the order

```
df[['Last_name', 'Name']] = df.Name.str.split(', ').str[::-1].apply(pd.Series)

df

    Name          City   Last_name
0    Hat         Paris    Richards
1    NaN      New york       Adams
2    Tim  Sanfrancisco     Mathews
3  chris     Las Vegas     Moya De
4   kate       Atlanta       Moris
5    NaN     Middleton  Grisham HA
```